# Ошибка при установке namecoin

Tags: linux, install, rpm, yum

Что он от меня хочет, кто нибудь сталкивался может с подобным

[image: вывод]

Comment: Ну так они под старую федору собирают - чё ты хотел? С убунтой чуть получше.

Comment: Как исправить? Собрать из исходников?

Comment: На офсайте архивы лежат.